# How to recover a corrupted Parallels 7 hard disk image?

Tags: macos, data-recovery, parallels

I have a Parallels virtual machine that has recently started to refuse to boot, with this error message:

Operation failed.
An error occured while reading the disk.
Support information: Problem ID: [21029](http://kb.parallels.com/en/10113)

If I click the problem ID, I’m taken to [this knowledge base article](http://kb.parallels.com/en/10113). It advises me to try and repair the Mac hard drive, which I've tried, but it reports no errors worth mentioning, and running it does not fix the Parallels disk.

It's a split, expanding image (ie. files in a folder, not a separate partition).

There used to be some additional tools shipped with Parallels to manage disk images for recovery, but they seem to have been phased out. Is there any way I might try to recover my disk?